# dpkg: Error processing package python-<package name>

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, apt-get

- I'm trying to upgrade my raspbian using `sudo apt-get upgrade`
  command, but it always gets me this error
- I tried this command  `sudo dpkg --configure -a` 
  and it shows me the same error
- I tried again to make a single configuration of each package, but with no 
  results.
  How can i configure the `dpkg`??

---

```
dpkg: error processing package python-idna (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-minecraftpi (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-crypto (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-fourletterphat (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-chardet (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-blinker (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-automationhat (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-colorama (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-cap1xxx (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-jwt (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-markupsafe (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-explorerhat:
 python-explorerhat depends on python-cap1xxx; however:
  Package python-cap1xxx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-explorerhat (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-keyrings.alt:
 python-keyrings.alt depends on python-crypto; however:
  Package python-crypto is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-keyrings.alt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package python-envirophat (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-imaging (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-configparser (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-gi (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-buttonshim (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-microdotphat (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-enum34 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-cryptography:
 python-cryptography depends on python-enum34; however:
  Package python-enum34 is not configured yet.
 python-cryptography depends on python-idna (>= 2.0); however:
  Package python-idna is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package python-gpiozero (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-requests:
 python-requests depends on python-chardet; however:
  Package python-chardet is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-requests (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: error processing package python-decorator (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-itsdangerous (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-blinkt (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-dbus (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package python-ipaddress (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-drumhat:
 python-drumhat depends on python-cap1xxx; however:
  Package python-cap1xxx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-drumhat (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-secretstorage:
 python-secretstorage depends on python-dbus; however:
  Package python-dbus is not configured yet.
 python-secretstorage depends on python-cryptography; however:
  Package python-cryptography is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-secretstorage (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-requests-oauthlib:
 python-requests-oauthlib depends on python-requests; however:
  Package python-requests is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-requests-oauthlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-oauthlib:
 python-oauthlib depends on python-blinker; however:
  Package python-blinker is not configured yet.
 python-oauthlib depends on python-cryptography; however:
  Package python-cryptography is not configured yet.
 python-oauthlib depends on python-jwt (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package python-jwt is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-oauthlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-keyring:
 python-keyring depends on python-dbus; however:
  Package python-dbus is not configured yet.
 python-keyring depends on python-secretstorage; however:
  Package python-secretstorage is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-keyring (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-pianohat:
 python-pianohat depends on python-cap1xxx; however:
  Package python-cap1xxx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-pianohat (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-jinja2:
 python-jinja2 depends on python-markupsafe; however:
  Package python-markupsafe is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-jinja2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-openssl:
 python-openssl depends on python-cryptography (>= 1.3.4); however:
  Package python-cryptography is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-openssl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-click:
 python-click depends on python-colorama; however:
  Package python-colorama is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-click (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-flask:
 python-flask depends on python-click; however:
  Package python-click is not configured yet.
 python-flask depends on python-itsdangerous; however:
  Package python-itsdangerous is not configured yet.
 python-flask depends on python-jinja2; however:
  Package python-jinja2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-flask (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-idna
 python-minecraftpi
 python-crypto
 python-fourletterphat
 python-chardet
 python-blinker
 python-automationhat
 python-colorama
 python-cap1xxx
 python-jwt
 python-markupsafe
 python-explorerhat
 python-keyrings.alt
 python-envirophat
 python-imaging
 python-configparser
 python-gi
 python-buttonshim
 python-microdotphat
 python-enum34
 python-cryptography
 python-gpiozero
 python-requests
 python-decorator
 python-itsdangerous
 python-blinkt
 python-dbus
 python-ipaddress
 python-drumhat
 python-secretstorage
 python-requests-oauthlib
 python-oauthlib
 python-keyring
 python-pianohat
 python-jinja2
 python-openssl
 python-click
 python-flask
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried to manually reinstall each package of those packages using this command

> sudo apt install --reinstall python-(package-name)

and it is solved :'D